# How to save and retrieve program settings when reboot (.NET & C#)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am building an application where a user can dynamically add buttons at runtime. 
However, I am not sure how I should be storing information without having to access a database. I have tried to store it in Properties.Settings.Default, but it does not support Button. Thus, I am using an XML file to store data. Is there any way to save button information (and all the other Controls) when the program terminates, and retrieve when restarted? (instead of using XML)

**Edit0**: just to make this question easier to understand, here is an example of what I am trying to achieve.
The application allows the user to add a new button and locate them by dragging. Right now, user is able to add new button and relocate it as needed. However, I am unable to save the state so that user can use the same 'layout' when the program restarts. I know that it is possible to save all state in a separate XML file, but this way seems very inefficient.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani How does a scheduled task help persist data?

Comment: define "button information"

Comment: Could you give more information such as is the a UWP / WPF  or a  win forms application and share some code of what you are currently doing?

Comment: As a side comment, I would suggest first to save "information" (whatever that means) as soon as it is known. You *could* wait for the application to end, but if it's from the shutdown/reboot, the system (would it be Windows or Linux or other) might not be letting enough time to actually save data.

Comment: Yeah the best way to do this is almost certainly through the UI framework so you need to tag that.

Comment: @Igor example of button information would be its name and location, etc.

Comment: @StuartSmith I am currently using winform to create the application. The sample code would just be accessing xml file and editing as needed. I am wondering if there is any alternative way to store system state other than Properties.Settings.Default or using additional XML file.